# from Google import Create_Service ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Google'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use Gmail api in python to send email but I cant get past importing the Google module despite using "pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client" or "pip install google".

However pip freeze shows:

```
asgiref==3.3.4
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
charset-normalizer==2.0.6
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.3
django-ckeditor==6.1.0
django-ckeditor-5==0.0.14
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-phone-field==1.8.1
django-tawkto==0.3
**google==3.0.0**
google-api-core==2.0.1
google-api-python-client==2.21.0
google-auth==2.1.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-cloud==0.34.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.26.0
google-cloud-core==2.0.0
google-cloud-storage==1.42.2
google-cloud-vision==2.4.2
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-resumable-media==2.0.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
grpcio==1.40.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
httplib2==0.19.1
idna==3.2
oauthlib==3.1.1
packaging==21.0
Pillow==8.2.0
proto-plus==1.19.0
protobuf==3.18.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-decouple==3.4
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.26.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.7.2
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.26.6
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

my code:

```
from Google import Create_Service
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
API_NAME = 'gmail'
API_VERSION = 'v1'
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Google.py` is in same dir?

Comment: google is part of the module installed through "pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client," so it should be accessed like any other module just like I can access "base64" from import base64

Comment: @Edith please can you let me know how did you resolve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create in folder of project file Google.py, here code of it

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
API_VERSION = api_version
SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
print(SCOPES)

cred = None

pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
# print(pickle_file)

if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
    with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
        cred = pickle.load(token)

if not cred or not cred.valid:
    if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
        cred.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        cred = flow.run_local_server()

    with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(cred, token)

try:
    service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
    print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
    return service
except Exception as e:
    print('Unable to connect.')
    print(e)
    return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
return dt
```

Comment: There is no indentation and import datetime in this code 

Answer (score 3):

Implicit relative imports are not anymore supported as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-import-system):

> There is no longer any implicit import machinery

So if `Google.py` is in the same directory as the code you pasted, you have to reference it's realtive location [explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports).

```
from .Google import Create_Service  # Notice the dot (.)
```

Or it can also be an absolute path. Assuming this is a Django project, then it would be something like:

```
from my_proj.Google import Create_Service  # This assumes that your file is in my_proj/my_proj/Google.py
```