# installed all libraries still:- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, modulenotfounderror

I am a mac user, using sublime text and this is the code,

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from Google import Create_Service

File = 'file.json'
Api = 'Drive'
apiVersion = 'V3'
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

- error: from Google import Create_Service ModuleNotFoundError: No
  module named 'Google'

**I have already installed google library

```
pip install google
pip install google-api-core
pip3 install google-api-python-client
ran all these commands
```

also updated it but still nothing works it shows the same error**

Comment: Check if it is `from Google import Create_Service` or `from google import Create_Service`

Comment: it is G capital one

Comment: Yes.. see, when you have `pip install google`, I think your import should be `from google` instead of `from Google`. It is evident from the error too which says, 'No module named Google'; so, the module name should be `google`  instead of `Google`

Comment: that worked  but now its showing this error,

```from google import Create_Service
ImportError: cannot import name 'Create_Service' from 'google' (unknown location)```

can you help with this one too?

Comment: Looks like Create_Service does not exist, and has to be a custom function. Please refer to the accepted answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69252673/from-google-import-create-service-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google

Comment: thank you for your help I'll figure it out, have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few of the imports

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```